# Rotation of text in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, vector, labeling

I am using Qgis 2.16 version .I have some basemap data but when I load it in the text layer (I can’t remember what its called but you should be able to see road names, house numbers etc) has an “orientation” field however I if I apply that field as an angle setting for the text it doesn’t align to roads, house orientation etc.

I guess because these are orientation values rather than angle values from 1-360 degrees?
the crs used is EPSG 27700 .

Can anyone help me to do anything with it to get it to render correctly?

---

What i need is not the alignment. i need to rotate the label according to the orientation. when i am using the orienation field for rotation. The label is not properly rendered. I am attaching the screen shot for your reference
[image]

---

I am attaching the screenshot of my attribute data for your reference. Im unable to attach the screenshot in comments that is y i am attaching here. please check and help me to sort out[image]

Comment: What software are you using?

Comment: Im using Qgis 2.16 version. CRS is EPSG 27700 british grid.

Comment: Please take the [Tour] to learn about the site and its protocols.  You can use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with additional details at any time.

Comment: Do you know what is the unit of your rotation field?

Comment: I don't know which dataset the screenshots are from but some of the OS data uses tenths of a degree as its orientation information (Page 15 here: http://digimap.edina.ac.uk/webhelp/os/data_files/os_manuals/os-vector-map-local-user-guide.pdf)

Comment: @EdRollason in this case user23288 should try using an expression with "orientatio"/10 and see what is obtained.

Comment: Thanks a lot. it works . Thank you so much. :) . can u explain the formula please.

Answer (score 1):

In order to align text on lines, you don't need to specify an orientation field. Labelling options already include the possibility to orientate labels on lines (above - on - below).
[image]

Comment: Where is your screenshot? Edit your post and add it. To me, alignment means rotation (see the screenshot in my answer: the label `2000` is rotated, no?).

Comment: see my screen shot. when I am assigning the orientation field for the rotation. its not properly rotated. hope u understand. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your text rotation value: 180-("orientatio"/10)